# Getting multiple Trello cards in a single request

Tags: trello

I need to get several cards from Trello API. I have their ids, e.g. "33ea503d91", "4e44503d91", "4e11103d91", "4eea500000".

Of cause, I can iterate over the array and send request to Trello API each time. But I would like to get it in one API-request. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API doesn't have a way to pull cards based on a specific list of card IDs as far as I know.

If all of the cards are on the same board or list, assigned to the same user, or share a label, you could use any of the API methods specific to those objects to pull all the cards you want in one call, then filter any extraneous cards by looping through the returned data locally.

Comment: label seems to be the way to go for this !